# Validity of Ohm's to non-steady currents

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-current

My textbook Griffiths electrodynamics says the current density at a point in a material is given by $j=\sigma f$, where '$\sigma$' is the conductivity and $f$ is the force per unit charge at that point. My question is can we say the above law is valid in the non-steady current density case in which the current might not be uniform and charges might be accumulating.For example during the transient stage of a simple DC circuit can we say that the above law holds?

Comment: Ohms law is derived under the assumption that the current is steady, this is done via the relevant differential equation. One such example where the standard formula is completely false is for the case of an AC current, Ohms law for this case becomes $\vec{J} = $re{$\sigma \vec{E} $} where the conductivity becomes complex, this  produces a phase difference between the applied electric field and the current density. The same is true for the situation you have stated, when the current is not constant, ohms law as it is typically stated is not accurate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you actually have charges accumulating, you need a more sophisticated model. If there's ohmic material in the circuit, Ohm's law still applies to it. But to analyze the effect of charge accumulation, you need at a minimum to consider the capacitances between the nodes where charge is accumulating. For many simple circuits this may be neglected. In others, you may even need a more sophisticated, fully electromagnetic model.

Remember that textbook idealizations are not real physics. Textbooks never fully explain their idealizations because they cannot practically do so: it would take a whole library, and it would still be incomplete. If trying to decode the idealizations is causing you frustration, I understand: I suffered the same frustration as a student.

Comment: Is there some most general version of ohm's law that would account for such situations then?

Comment: @Arjun There is no *most* general version: one adds details to the ohmic model as needed. But in the case you're talking about, the concept of resistance generalizes to the concept of "impedance". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_impedance.

Answer (score 3):

Ohm's law, $\mathbf J = \sigma \mathbf E$ is not a "law" in the sense of, say, $\text{div} \mathbf b =0$. The latter is a mathematical expression of the fact that there no magnetic charges, while the former is a constitutive equation of a particular macroscopic material and current subject to a macroscopic electric field.

It is a constitutive relationship in the sense as the ideal gas "law" is in thermodynamics. There are physical quantities: pressure $p$, volume $V$, number of molecules $N$ and temperature $T$ and for that particular set of quantities we have an equation showing their relationship: $pV=Nk_bT$. This is not a law, it is rather the definition of what we mean by an "ideal gas". Some real gasses in certain range of the variables get quite close to satisfy this equation, others do not.

Another example of a constitutive relationship would be Hooke's force law $F=-k(T)(x-x_0)$ for an elastic material. If you stretch anything far enough it will break and will surely be the end of "Hooke", but in a certain range of $x$ and $F$ it is quite useful and, of course, the $k(T)$ is not just temperature but also material dependent.

Ohm's law is in the same category. In the microscopic version of Maxwell's equation there is no Ohm's law, you only have two microscopic fields, $\mathbf e$ and $\mathbf b$, and the Lorentz's force law describing the forces on a elementary charge $q_e$ moving with velocity $\mathbf v$ in a given $\mathbf {e,b}$ field pair, and there are no $ \rho,\mathbf {J, E,B,H,D}$.

When the microscopic fields averaged over time and space with the motions of the charges that is when you get the macroscopic fields $\rho,\mathbf {J, E,B,H,D}$ and the macroscopic Maxwell's equations. Those averages are always to be performed in specific circumstances, for example, it could be a nearly stationary background of positive ions in which charges, electrons, may move more or less freely and the ions, while localized, may vibrate randomly. These are assumptions that may or may not be applicable in a particular circumstance but a fairly large class of materials, the "electric conductors", do fall in this category. Such a situation will lead to a functional relationship between the macroscopic $\mathbf J$ and the macroscopic $\mathbf E$.

If this relationship is $f(\mathbf J, \mathbf E)=0$ for some two variable vector function $f(\cdot, \cdot)$ then we talk about a general Ohmic conductor, and if the relationship is also linear you get what is usually referred to as Ohm's law. Note too that already at this level actually it should be $f(\mathbf J, \mathbf E, T)=0$, the conductivity is, in fact, always temperature dependent. But there is no reason why it could not depend also on a magnetic field, and there are materials that do show such dependence. Furthermore,  nothing prohibits that the current be also dependent on the time and spatial rates of the bias field explicitly, and certainly in a material where charges may accumulate, say, at a semiconductor pn junction you get a capacitive effect in addition to the ohmic current, and then you have a relationship such as $g(\mathbf J, \mathbf E, \mathbf D, T)=0$, and no law would prohibit that.

Answer (score 2):

Ohms law is derived under the assumption that the current is steady, this is done via the relevant differential equation. One such example where the standard formula is completely false is for the case of an AC current, Ohms law for this case becomes $\vec{J} = $re{$\sigma \vec{E} $} where the conductivity becomes complex, this  produces a phase difference between the applied electric field and the current density. The same is true for the situation you have stated, when the current is not constant, ohms law as it is typically stated is not accurate

Ohms law is the steady state solution of a simple dc circuit, the transient stage of the dc circuit is not applicable to Ohms law ,since by its derivation, we wait until the transient stage is over.

Comment: "Ohms law is the steady state solution of a simple dc circuit" can we show that a given dc circuit will always reach a steady state mathematically, I have seen a lot of heuristic arguments in books that speak about charges accumulating initially until everything is smoothed out but no one rigorously shows it.

Comment: "Ohms law is derived under the assumption that the current is steady". Is that really true?  It makes it sound that ohms law doesn't apply to ac circuits unless by current you are referring to a constant rms value. Moreover, doesn't Ohms law apply to transient conditions if we simply write it in the form $v(t)=i(t)R$ for a resistor?

Comment: @BobD the drude model of conductivity which is used to derive ohms law, uses a differential equation that is alike to the terminal velocity of an object falling, It is  derived also  using a constant electric field, and hence any application of ohms law for AC currents is fundamentally flawed.  Ohms law in general does apply with modifications, this more general ohms law is not what I would consider OP is talking about which is why I stated it does not work. Although I have not tried to model the transient stage in the form as you have described, I suspect that this is not an accurate model-

Comment: Naively using ohms law at a particular moment in time where the current distribution happens to have some instantatios value does not take into account the exponential term that is present when deriving ohms law during the transient stage, simply omitting this term and using the steady state solution of a model whilst it Is still going through the transient stage is not mathematically consistent and indicative of what is actually going on. I assume since you have mentioned it, people have attempted to model the transient stage like this, however mathematically it is flawed and an approximation

Comment: @Arjun the model in which ohms law is derived from, uses a force term that is proportional to the velocity. It can be shown that modelling the complex interactions that the electrons have with the lattice using this simple model will always produce a steady state.( atleast the model of a constant force, wire bends are not taken into account in this model though, so I cannot comment)

Comment: @jensenpaull Not sure I follow you, but Knzhou's answer in the following link states the Drude Model is no longer "remotely true". https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/625667/a-contradiction-between-the-drude-model-and-ohms-law